# Slider Thumbnail Size Issue

Tags: functions, post-thumbnails, slideshow

My website http://www.ianuranjan.com features a slider on the front page and i'm having issues with the uniformity of its thumbnail sizes. Please, help me out.The slider thumbnail size in the function.php is 600*400. The left most thumbnail is true to the code. But the other two aren't.[image: This is a Screenshot of the slider]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on a good track.

1. You first define your thumbnail sizes in your functions.php
2. Make you upload big high-quality images but still good enough for the web
3. You then need to regenerate your thumbnail, I recommend this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/
4. In you new code, you need to call your desired thumbnail based on the size you have provided, e.g. `<?php get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, 'my-slider-img' );  ?>`